# What is the best way to deploy authenticated autoupdates in a .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, deployment

Currently applications are deployed only to my office of 40 employees or so.  ClickOnce works great for this as everyone has network access or VPN access which makes updating pretty straightforward.  Now, it has been tasked to me to figure out the best way to deploy these applications to res of the company.  ClickOnce would work but the files would be made publicly available to any.

What would be the easiest way to implement this feature with some form of authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual deploy page can be set up on a site that requires Windows Authentication. As long as the domain controller you are using trusts the other domain controllers, you are golden. You might be able to do this at the folder level, as well. If you go this route, you can still use the click once model.

There are a few more ideas here:
http://tinyurl.com/bn5e76

Comment: Try this URL: http://tinyurl.com/bn5e76, as the other is not a good link anymore.